# Angular Nested Controller Scope Inheritance Problem

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm having some weird problem here I have already declared a scope data in my main controller and can access it in every other controller except this child controller I just made, when I log/use `$scope.user` in the `child controller` the value is `undefined`

Main Controller

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app.ctrls', []);
        var app = angular.module('app.ctrls');
        app.controller('mainCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope){
            $scope.user = {
                name:"John Doe",
                id: 4
            };
    }]);
})();
```

Child Controller

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("app.ctrls");
    app.controller("childCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
        console.log($scope.user);
    }]);
})();
```

Route

```
var app = angular.modules("app.configs");
    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ( 
    $routeProvider, $locationProvider ) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/settings/basic_info', {
            templateUrl: 'basic_info_settings.html',
            controller: 'childCtrl',
            title: 'Basic Info - Settings | Knoweldge First'
        })
}]);
```

View

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-view> 

</div>
```

Comment: @BhojendraNepal fixed the typo, that's not it.

Comment: What is your HTML structure? Is the childCtrl included into the mainCtrl on the view?

Comment: @ArtyomPranovich no through the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) This issue related with your html structure.

If you want to inherit parent's controller scope, you should create **nested** structure of your controllers on the view. You can restructure your html smth like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

In this case angular will know, that every new controller's scope should be inherited from parent's controller scope.

I've created **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shepard_one/J5hRc/147/)** example for you with the same case.

2) Also you can solve this problem with using of **resolve** object.

For example:

```
.when('/settings/basic_info', {
            templateUrl: 'basic_info_settings.html',
            controller: 'childCtrl',
            resolve: {
               user: function(userService){
                  return userService.getUser();
               }
            }
        })
```

Where `userService`:

```
app.factory("messageService", function($http){
    var factory = {
       getUser: function() {
          var promise = $http({ 
              method: 'GET', 
              url: 'api/user'
          })
          .success(function(data) {
              return data;
          });
          return promise;
       }
    };
    return factory;
});
```

Angular show this route only when all promises will be resolved and you can just use `user` object, which is injected into the controller.

```
app.controller("childCtrl", ["$scope", user, function($scope, user){
     $scope.user = user;
}]);
```